# Multiple domain cookies handling using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, cookies, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I save all cookies for gmail login. I use this cookies when I login again in gmail I load this cookies file but I can not login with this cookies get exception like **"*Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidCookieDomainException: You may only set cookies for the current domain*"**

My code is look like:

```
    File f = new File("c:\\browser.data");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(fb, fp);
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("Email")).sendKeys("myusername");
    driver.findElement(By.name("Passwd")).sendKeys("mypassword");
    driver.findElement(By.name("PersistentCookie")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("signIn")).submit();
    Thread.sleep(20000);

    try {
        f.delete();
        f.createNewFile();
        try (FileWriter fos = new FileWriter(f); BufferedWriter bos = new BufferedWriter(fos)) {

            for (Cookie ck : driver.manage().getCookies()) {
                bos.write((ck.getName() + ";" + ck.getValue() + ";" + ck.getDomain() + ";" + ck.getPath() + ";" + ck.getExpiry() + ";" + ck.isSecure()));
                bos.newLine();
            }

            bos.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".gb_V.gbii")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gb_71']")).click();
    driver.close();
    WebDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver(pf);
    driver1.get("https://accounts.google.com");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(line, ";");
        while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String name = str.nextToken();
            String value = str.nextToken();
            String domain = str.nextToken();
            String path = str.nextToken();
            Date expiry = null;
            String dt;
            if (!(dt=str.nextToken()).equals("null")) {

                expiry =new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d H:m:s z y").parse(dt);
            }
            boolean isSecure = Boolean.valueOf(str.nextToken()).booleanValue();
            Cookie ck1 = new Cookie(name, value, domain, path, expiry, isSecure);
            System.out.println(domain);
                if (domain.equalsIgnoreCase(".google.com")) {
                    driver1.get("https://accounts.google.com/ ");
                    driver1.manage().addCookie(ck);
                    driver1.get("https://accounts.google.com/ ");
                }

                if (domain.equalsIgnoreCase(".mail.google.com")) {
                    //driver1.get("http://accounts.google.com");
                    driver1.get("http://mail.google.com");
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    driver1.manage().addCookie(ck);
                    //driver1.get("http://accounts.google.com");
                    driver1.get("http://mail.google.com");
                }

        }
    }
```

After getting long search I cannot get any solution or workaround for this.

As I understand that this type of error occurred when single login validate the multiple domain.

I really need to login in gmail using cookies.  This is for an example there are several site where this implements then how can we handle this in selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 1):

It’s not clear which domain or which cookie is causing trouble. This simple code is working for me:

```
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com");
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("foo", "bar", ".google.com", "/", new Date(), true);
driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com“);
```

Note that google is returning a wildcard-domain in the cookie. So you must open a valid subdomain before you set the cookie. GoogleMail is also setting cookies for `.mail.google.com` and `plus.google.com`. So check all cookies and open a valid domain for each cookie before setting it.

This can get tricky because google might redirect you. For instance if I’m opening https://mail.google.com/ and I’m not logged in I’m getting a redirect to https://accounts.google.com.

Comment: thanks for your help....I modify my given question I add more code by which you can understand what i am doing actually.Here you can understand that main problem creator is .main.google.com please go through my code and rectify me if i made a mess in code.

Comment: If you go through my code then see I login my gmail add write all cookies into a file and close the browser and again launch the browser and feed the cookies from file ......I also do this with facebook and I login in facebook using the cookies,why not for gmail,you can say multidomain problem but how can I resolve this please help me.

Comment: Tried your code and didn’t get it working. Calling ```mail.google.com``` redirects me to ```accounts.google.com``` so it’s not possible to set a cookie with selenium. But with all cookies from ````.google.com``` you are logged in and can access e.g. https://www.google.com/settings/personalinfo. I guess you need a oAuth-Token to proceed to the other applications so maybe [that helps](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments....can you please give some code snippet how to use this in selenium webdriver.if you can it's really help me.....